# Using HIdden Markov Model for prediction

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction, hidden-markov-models, markov

Suppose there is a sequence of observations,e.g. `[1,2,3,5,5,5,2,3,2,3, ..., 3, 4]`. I am trying to use the current implementation of HMM in Scikit-learn to predict the next value of this observation sequence. I have 2 questions regarding this.

1. Given a sequence of observations, how do I predict the next observation(as mentioned above)?
2. Given many sequences of n observations and n+1 observations of those sequences, can HMM be used to predict the (n+1)th observation of a new sequence of n observations? If so how?

I couldn't grasp much about this from the documentation.

I found a likely [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628696/hidden-markov-model-predicting-next-observation), but it doesn't specify on how to use HMM in Scikit-learn to predict the next value in a sequence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HMMs are not a good fit for this problem. They're good at for predicting the labels (hidden states) of a fully observed sequence, not for completing a sequence. Try training a classifier or regression model on windows of observations, then use that for prediction. I.e. at training time give the model observations `(i, ..., i + k)` as features and observation `i + k + 1` as the target, for all positions `i` in each of your given sequences. At test time, feed the last `k` observations as features.

Comment: Yes. I've realized HMM wont work here. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

This is a time series task, there's no reason to believe HMMs would work here.

I'd suggest you look at time series methods---there's a family of methods called [ARIMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) which should work nicely.